# Check for the element inside the nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, lodash

I have below json

```
const data = {
    rooms: [
        {
            roomId: 1,
            schedules: [
                { home1: "06:00", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "21:30" },
                { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "22:30" }
            ]
        },
        {
            roomId: 2,
            schedules: [
                { home1: "06:00", dayOfWeek: 4, away: "21:30" },
                { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "22:30" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I need to push the above elements for the dayOfWeek which are not present inside the `schedules` array of both the `rooms`

This is the output I want

```
const finalOuput = [
    //for room 1
    { home1: "00:00", dayOfWeek: 3, away: "02:30", roomId: 1 },
    { home1: "00:00", dayOfWeek: 4, away: "02:30", roomId: 1 },
    { home1: "00:00", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "02:30", roomId: 1 },
    { home1: "00:00", dayOfWeek: 6, away: "02:30", roomId: 1 },
    { home1: "00:00", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "02:30", roomId: 1 },
    //for room 2
    { home1: "00:00", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "02:30", roomId: 2 },
    { home1: "00:00", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "02:30", roomId: 2 },
    { home1: "00:00", dayOfWeek: 3, away: "02:30", roomId: 2 },
    { home1: "00:00", dayOfWeek: 6, away: "02:30", roomId: 2 },
    { home1: "00:00", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "02:30", roomId: 2 },
]
```

I have tried loop over the `rooms` array something like This

```
const finalOuput = []
rooms.map((room) => {
    room.schedules.map((schedule) => {
        finalOuput.push(schedule)
    })
})
```

But don't know how to check for the `dayOfWeek` which are not present inside the `rooms` schedules.

Can someone please help to acheive this. Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why did all the times get changed, and what is the purpose of the `const object = { ... }`? Can you elaborate?

Comment: What is home and away time in output?

Comment: @TylerRoper I have updated. I need to push only those elements(dayOfWeek) inside the `finalOutput` array which are not present in both the `rooms` schedules. Please check the `finalOuput` array elements. It has only those `dayOfWeek` which are not present inside the both the `rooms` and also `roomId` is the unique key in that.

Comment: @Vivek It is just a key. We can take any key.

Comment: As in the values of those key should be computed?

Comment: @Vivek no they are also static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ES6 only solution**:

```js
const data = { rooms: [{ roomId: 1, schedules: [{ home1: "06:00", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "21:30", roomId: 1 }, { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "22:30", roomId: 1 } ] }, { roomId: 2, schedules: [{ home1: "06:00", dayOfWeek: 4, away: "21:30", roomId: 2 }, { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "22:30", roomId: 2 } ] } ] }

const getSchedules = (room) => {
  let weekDays = [...Array(8).keys()]
  weekDays.shift()
  let days = weekDays.filter(x => !room.schedules.some(y => y.dayOfWeek == x))
  return days.map(y => ({ home1: "00:00", dayOfWeek: y, away: "02:30", roomId: room.roomId }))
}

console.log(data.rooms.reduce((r,c) => (r.push(...getSchedules(c)), r), []))
```

**Lodash version:**

```js
const data = { rooms: [{ roomId: 1, schedules: [{ home1: "06:00", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "21:30", roomId: 1 }, { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "22:30", roomId: 1 } ] }, { roomId: 2, schedules: [{ home1: "06:00", dayOfWeek: 4, away: "21:30", roomId: 2 }, { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "22:30", roomId: 2 } ] } ] }

const getSchedules = (room) => {
  let days = _.difference(_.range(1,8), _.map(room.schedules, 'dayOfWeek'))
  return days.map(y => ({ home1: "00:00", dayOfWeek: y, away: "02:30", roomId: room.roomId }))
}
console.log(_.reduce(data.rooms, (r,c) => (r.push(...getSchedules(c)), r), []))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The idea is to use the the difference between the range of `1...7` and the current days in each `room.schedule` via ([**`_.difference`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#difference) & [**`_.range`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#range) in lodash and [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in ES6) and just hydrate the result in the resulting output.

Comment: Thank you Akrion I will surely upvote when I get 15 reps. Just a small bug It pushes all the 14 elements inside the array. I need which are not present the schedules. Any thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array all the days of the week and filter if by whether that day exists in you `schedules` array.

Then map over the filtered array and build your objects:

```js
const data = {rooms: [{roomId: 1,schedules: [{ home1: "06:00", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "21:30" },{ home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "22:30" }]},{roomId: 2,schedules: [{ home1: "06:00", dayOfWeek: 4, away: "21:30" },{ home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "22:30" }]}]}

const days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
const template =  { home1: "00:00", away: "02:30",  }

const rooms = data.rooms.reduce((arr, {roomId, schedules}) => {
  // missing is the days no presesnt in schedules
  let missing = days.filter(day => !schedules.find(s => s.dayOfWeek == day ))
  return arr.concat( ... missing.map(d =>  Object.assign({}, template, {dayOfWeek: d,room: roomId})))
        
}, [])
console.log(rooms)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code

```js
const data = {
    rooms: [
        {
            roomId: 1,
            schedules: [
                { home1: "06:00", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "21:30" },
                { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "22:30" }
            ]
        },
        {
            roomId: 2,
            schedules: [
                { home1: "06:00", dayOfWeek: 4, away: "21:30" },
                { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "22:30" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
let output = []
for (let room of data.rooms) {
  let days = []
  room.schedules.map(s => days.push(parseInt(s.dayOfWeek)))
  days = new Set(days)
  for(let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    if(!days.has(i)) output.push({ 'home1': '00:00', 'dayOfWeek': i, 'away': '02:30', 'roomId': room.roomId })
  }
}
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Code:

```js
const data = {rooms: [{roomId: 1,schedules: [{ home1: "06:00", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "21:30" },{ home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "22:30" }]},{roomId: 2,schedules: [{ home1: "06:00", dayOfWeek: 4, away: "21:30" },{ home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "22:30" }]}]}
const finalOuput = data.rooms.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    .filter(d => !c.schedules.find(s => s.dayOfWeek === d))
    .map(availableDay => ({
      roomId: c.roomId,
      home1: '00:00',
      dayOfWeek: availableDay,
      away: '02:30'
    }))
), []);

console.log(finalOuput);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```